# Styled components react-native components not detecting Type (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

Following is a sample component in react-native with Styled components.

```js
import { FC } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export const Test: FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StyledView onLayout={(event) => null}></StyledView>
      <View onLayout={(event) => null}></View>
    </>
  );
};

const StyledView = styled.View`
  width: 100%;
`;
```

The issue is that for the StyledView component, typescript just fails to identify any props or type check it at all.

The type for `onLayout` prop for the StyledView is shown as follows:

```
(property) onLayout: (event: any) => null
```

The type for `onLayout` prop for the default `View` is shown as follows:

```
(property) onLayout?: ((event: LayoutChangeEvent) => void) | undefined
```

The type hint for the StyledView component itself is as follows:

```
const StyledView: StyledComponent<typeof View, DefaultTheme, {}, never>
```

So it's not like typescript is entirely clueless. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or if the explanation above even gives enough context.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I having the same issue here :(